# A generalization of GMRES

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

In order to solve $Ax=b$, GMRES method finds $x_n$ in the $n$-th Krylov subspace i.e.:

$$K_n=\text{span}\{b,Ab,...,A^{n-1}\}$$

and we have the condition: minimize $\|r_n\|_2$, which $r_n=b-Ax_n$

Now we have a new condition instead of the previous one: $r_n \perp K_n$

How to gain the least square problem like the one in GMRES?

**Well**, I met this problem in a test few days ago.

[image]

**I** think there must be something wrong with this problem:

In the 3rd line $r_m \perp AK_m$
How could this be?For $r_m$ is actually in $K_{m+1}$ then $r_n\parallel b$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if $x_m\in x_0+K_m$, then $r_m:=b-Ax_m\in r_0+AK_m\subset K_{m+1}$. The GMRES method defines the iterate $x_m$ such that
$$
\|r_m\|_2=\|b-Ax_m\|_2=\min_{y\in x_0+K_m}\|b-Ay\|_2=\min_{c\in K_m}\|r_0-Ac\|_2
=\min_{d\in AK_m}\|r_0-d\|_2.
$$
It is well known that an optimization over a subspace is equivalent to certain orthogonality of the error. We have that the GMRES residual is given by $r_m=r_0-d_m$ so that
$$
\|r_m\|_2=\|r_0-d_m\|_2=\min_{d\in AK_m}\|r_0-d\|_2,
$$
which is *equivalent* to
$$
r_m=r_0-d_m\perp AK_m.
$$

---

You might replace the condition $r_m\perp AK_m$ (equivalent to minimizing the 2-norm of the residual and leading to GMRES) by $r_m\perp K_m$. This defines another method usually called FOM, which, if $A$ is SPD, reduces to conjugate gradients which minimize the $A$-norm of the error $x-x_m$ (so FOM can be considered as "CG for nonsymmetric systems").

Indeed, if $A$ is SPD, we have that
$$
r_0-d_m\perp K_m
\quad \Leftrightarrow \quad
A^{-1/2}r_m=A^{-1/2}r_0-f_m\perp A^{1/2}K_m,
$$
where $f_m:=A^{-1/2}d_m\in A^{1/2}K_m$ since $d_m\in AK_m$. So we have $A^{-1/2}r_0$ plus something in $A^{1/2}K_m$ which is supposed to be orthogonal to $A^{1/2}K_m$ as well. This is hence equivalent to
$$
\|A^{-1/2}r_m\|_2=\|A^{-1/2}r_0-f_m\|_2=\min_{f\in A^{1/2}K_m}\|A^{-1/2}r_0-f\|_2.
$$
Hence the FOM (CG) if $A$ is SPD minimizes the 2-norm of $A^{-1/2}r_m$. Note that if $e_m:=x-x_m$, we have
$$
\|A^{-1/2}r_m\|_2=\|r_m\|_{A^{-1}}=\|A^{1/2}e_m\|_2=\|e_m\|_A.
$$

---

Note that in GMRES, the approximate solution is obtained from a small least squares problem with an $(m+1)\times m$ upper Hessenberg matrix computed by the Arnoldi algorithm. However, FOM approximation is determined by solving a linear system with an $m\times m$ (again) upper Hessenberg matrix. There's no difference in solving both the least-squares and the square system (except that the latter might be singular occasionally) as they upper Hessenberg matrices are reduced to triangular forms "on-fly" with essentially the same costs in both methods.

Comment: Thanks a lot.btw,I wonder how to prove the 2nd problem.By the definition of $r_m$ ,$r_m \perp AK_m$ where $K_m=\{b,Ab...,A_{m-1}\}$ so $v_i=A^ib$ in the problem.Then it is obvious that $r_k \perp v_i(1\le i \le m-1)$ What does the teacher want me to prove?(here I choose $x_0=0$)

Comment: @paradox Oh now I get it. It actually is not the standard GMRES formulation but something what is behind the so-called "simpler" GMRES ($v_0$ is not orthogonal to $v_i$, $i\geq 1$, here). So if you start an Arnoldi method with the initial vector $Av_0/\|Av_0\|_2$, then you obtain at step $k$ the vectors $\{v_1,\ldots,v_k\}$, which form an orthonormal basis of $AK_k$. Since $r_k\perp AK_k$, we have $r_k\perp v_i$, $i=1,\ldots,k$.